Target class [files] does not exist
i want to add a sweet alert on my code, but when i do this it gives me this error i use laravel 12
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\cp_segar_jegad> php artisan sweetalert:publish
   
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [files] does not exist.

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:906
    902▕
    903▕         try {
    904▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    905▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 906▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    907▕         }
    908▕
    909▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    910▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Spatie\LaravelIgnition\IgnitionServiceProvider))

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:904
      ReflectionException::("Class "files" does not exist")`

i put both of this code to my terminal and then now it have that error please help!
composer require realrashid/sweet-alert

RealRashid\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider::class,


"i use laravel 12" Highly unlikely

" when i do this" what is it that you did exactly ?

This happens when you have not registered the Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider.

How would this answer the current issue?

doesn't work for me
